# How to get the values from hashmap and display the quiz app..?

Tags: android, textview, radio-button, hashmap

Im facing a problem in quiz app...

My problem is..

I got the Questionid, questions and answers through JSON. And i stored in hashmap with single key. Now What i want to do is...

How can i get the question and answers from hashmap based upon questionid..to display the question in textview and answers in radiobuttons...

How can i implement this?  Any help would be appreciated...Thanks a lot in advance..

> ```
>   protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>    pDialog.dismiss();   
>        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", tid));
>     JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesid, "GET", params);
>     json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesurl, "GET", params);
>       try {
>     int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>     if (success == 1) {
>     System.out.println("Success");
>     groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
>     System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
>     for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
>     JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
>     String questionid = c.getString(TAG_QUESID);
>     String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
>     String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);
>     System.out.println("Checking ::"+questionid);
>     id=questionid;         
>     quesid.add(questionid);
>     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
>     map.put(questionid,  question + ";" + answer);                  
>     System.out.println("QuestionIDMap:"+map);
>         }
>     } else {
>     showAlert();
> }
>     } catch (JSONException e) {
>     System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
>     }       
> }
> ```

Comment: The JSON part is working correctly? Are the objects created and stored successfully? If so, no need to post that part of the code. Also your `map` is local to `onCreate()` and as such it will be destroyed when `onCreate()` finishes, is this what you want? Also you're inserting `TAG_QUESID` as the key and not `questionId`...

Comment: ehm..what about map.get(questionid) ... ?

Comment: @m0skit0 yes Json part all working successfully..and TAG_QUESID is my key...Now how can i implement to display the question and answers...

Comment: @stefan de bruijn i got the questionid, question and answer option in map.put(..) itself..frnd..

Comment: I've got no idea what you want to achieve. Why do you not just use the qustionid as key for the map.

Comment: Then please clean your code from JSON, just makes your code harder to read and it's irrelevant to the question. You said *"TAG_QUESID is my key"* but in your question you also say *"hashmap based upon questionid"*. So which one is the key? Looks like you have a big confusion about what you want to do.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes i edit my code questionid as key..Now how can i implement to display the question and answers...

Comment: @stefan de bruijn yes i edit my code questionid as key..Now how can i implement to display the question and answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you want to use your questionid as the map key.

Once you've got that ,you can simply do something simular to;

String total = map.get(questionid); 
String[] split = total.split(";");

String question = split[0];
String answer = split[1];

---

In total i'd rather recommend using a database though, then saving everything in collections.

Comment: ok, then how can i get the question into textview and answers in radiobuttons

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` is local to `onCreate()`. This means when `onCreate()` finishes, **your map is destroyed** and you can't access it anymore. Move map as a field of your `Activity`. Then you can just access it from wherever you want and do `map.get(questionId)` to get the question.

Your Activity would look like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private HashMap<String, String> questions = new HashMap<String, String>();



    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
       pDialog.dismiss();   
           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", tid));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesid, "GET", params);
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_quesurl, "GET", params);
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                System.out.println("Success");
                groups = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GROUP);
                System.out.println("Result Success+++"+groups);
                for (int i = 0; i < groups.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
                    String questionid = c.getString(TAG_QUESID);
                    String question = c.getString(TAG_QUES);
                    String answer = c.getString(TAG_ANSW);
                    System.out.println("Checking ::"+questionid);
                    id=questionid;         
                    quesid.add(questionid);         
                    questions.put(questionid,  question + ";" + answer);                  
                    System.out.println("QuestionIDMap:"+map);
                }
            } else {
                showAlert();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            System.out.println("Error "+e.toString());
        }       
    }
}
```

Then you can access the question anywhere from your `Activity` by doing `questions.get(questionId)`.

Comment: yes i done..now can i implement the question and answer to display